# How to use FFMPEG to stack two equirectangular images to top/bottom format?

Tags: ffmpeg, 3d, stereo

This command line does what I need, but it is a little tricky...

```
ffmpeg -i left.jpg -i right.jpg -filter_complex "[0]scale=iw:ih*2[grande],[grande][0]overlay=x=0:y=0[base],[base][1]overlay=x=0:y=h" -y top-bottom.jpg

 - -i left.jpg          Left image
 - -i right.jpg         Right image
 - -filter_complex 
 - "[0]scale=iw:ih*2[grande],
      enlarge vertically image 1 to double its height, and create stream "grande" 
      (i.e. just create a base image twice high the input image)
 - [grande][0]overlay=x=0:y=0[base],
      Overlay image 1 to stream "grande", i.e. put left image in upper part of main image; 
      the results goes into "base" stream
 - [base][1]overlay=x=0:y=h"
      Overlay image 2 to bottom part of "base" stream, which already contains upper (left) image
```

Does it exist a more straightforward method? I see they exists "in_stereo" and "out_stereo" options, with "2d" and "tb" (Top-Bottom) options, but I don't understand if they are what I need, and I can't find any documentation.

Sample images:

1:

[image: top left]

2:

[image: bottom right]

Comment: Use the vstack filter as shown in [Vertically or horizontally stack (mosaic) several videos using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33764934/)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
ffmpeg -i left.jpg -i right.jpg -filter_complex "[0]scale=iw:ih*2[grande],[grande][0]overlay=x=0:y=0[base],[base][1]overlay=x=0:y=h" -y top-bottom.jpg
```

Can be simplified in:

```
ffmpeg -i left.jpg -i right.jpg -filter_complex vstack=inputs=2 -y top-bottom.jpg
```